# Vertica 6.0.1 Install faild on local machine

Tags: python, vertica

I am trying to install Vertica Community edition on a 3 node cluster. I am facing the below error the moment i ran the command in Linux.

Command : /opt/vertica/sbin/install_vertica -s Node01,Node02,Node03 -r vertica-ce-6.0.1-0.x86_64.RHEL5.rpm

Error : Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/vertica/bin/verticaInstall.py", line 25, in 
from vertica.network import SSH, adapterpool
ImportError: No module named vertica.network
Installation failed.

Please help me out on this. I have no clue with python language and don't know what exactly i am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

try install Vertica 6.1.3 from https://my.vertica.com